# Does ShellExecute() and ShellExecuteEx() calls CreateProcess() internally?

Tags: winapi

I've read in a couple of places that ShellExecute() and ShellExecuteEx() calls CreateProcess() internally, is this true? is it documented somewhere in MSDN?

Comment: They are winapi functions, doesn't have much to do with the way Windows works.  Windows provides only one way to create a process, NtCreateProcess().  The native api is largely undocumented.

Comment: What is the programming problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `ShellExecuteEx` calls `CreateProcess` internally, as you can easily show by setting a breakpoint on `CreateProcess` and then making a call to `ShellExecuteEx`:

[image: call stack from ShellExecute to CreateProce]

Comment: I assume that ShellExecute() is the same as ShellExecuteEx()?

Comment: Yes it's just a thin wrapper function.

Comment: Note, however, that this is not contractual.  That is, it might change in a future version of Windows.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't call `CreateProcess`. It depends on what you are executing.